# Proguard: how to proguard META-INF/services interface and impl names?

Tags: proguard, service-locator, meta-inf

Proguard: how to proguard META-INF/services interface and impl names for service loader?

e.g.

```
META-INF/services/com.example.Foo
com.example.impl.FooImpl
```

Is there a way for proguard to obfuscate the interface and impl class names? i.e. their class names do not need to be kept and META-INF/services will be changed accordingly. e.g. after obfuscation:

```
META-INF/services/com.example.a
com.example.b.a
```

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found a solution to that? Thanks!